How to locate Android kernel sensor drivers in source code for Pixel 7a (lynx)?
I am developing a custom ROM for the Pixel 7a (lynx) running Android 13, using the custom kernel branch android-gs-lynx-5.10-android13-qpr3. However, I am struggling to find the actual driver code responsible for physical sensors (e.g., Accelerometer, Magnetometer, Proximity, Light sensors, etc.).
i found the some part of code related to accelerometer in the KERNEL_ROOT/aosp/drivers/iio/accel/, when i tried to make changes it is not reflected on the build.
Could anyone guide me on where to find actual sensor drivers in the Android kernel source? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

You need first to know your hardware, second, look into the actual kernel configuration file.

the following are the vendor details of Accelerometer sensor
Sensor Name: LSM6DSV Accelerometer
Vendor: STMicro
Version: 1
Type: android.sensor.accelerometer
Driver: android.sensor.accelerometer
when i searched with string 'LSM6DSV' in the source code i didn't find any matches

No, you need to see which driver is used in the Linux kernel and what interface it has. In the vanilla kernel the closest driver is https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.226/source/drivers/iio/imu/st_lsm6dsx/Kconfig. I dunno what the difference in V variant in comparison to the supported ones.

Okay, the vanilla kernel starting from v6.2 does support this variant of the sensor chip. So, you either need to update the kernel from v5.10 to v6.2 or backport the necessary pieces. Each of the tasks is not so trivial (however the latter might be easier to fulfill) due to big distance between kernel versions in question. OTOH, you have a vendor kernel which may have that support enabled. Consult with the vendor of the board you have.

when i do changes in vanilla version of https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.157/source/drivers/iio/imu/st_lsm6dsx,  but they are not getting reflcted in the final  build, how can i differentiate the driver which is actually working on the device, and the corresponding driver source code.

how do you know the changes are not reflected to the build?

i kept some debug statements in the code after compiling the Kernel source code and flash it on to the device they are not triggering.
